# How to create madata in R?

Tags: r

How to create madata?

```
write.madata(madata, datafile="madata.txt", designfile="design.txt")
```

I have the following links

- http://cgd.jax.org/churchill-apps/jmaanova-1.0.0/help/8e11221e.html
- http://rgm2.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=maanova:write.madata

But do not understand how to create them for the dataset I have created.

For example: How to convert a data set like this to madata:

```
ID        Name      Age

1         ABC       15

2         PQR       80

3         XZY       15
```

Comment: You are likely to have better response to this question on the Bioconductor mailing list ...

Answer (score 1):

From the help page that you linked [`?read.madata`](http://cgd.jax.org/churchill-apps/jmaanova-1.0.0/help/8e11221e.html), all you have to do is call `read.madata`  with a matrix or tab delimited file as the first argument.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.

What I meant is that suppose I have data set like
(ID      Name       Age)
(1       ABC        15)
(2       PQR        80)
(3       XZY        15)
How do I convert this to madata?